# Keypress Refer to Topmost Modal

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I have a `Modal` component, which uses Bulma CSS' [modal](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/):

```html
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    export let active;
    export let closeable = true;
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    const closeModal = () => {
        active = false;
        dispatch("closeModal");
    };

    const closeModalSoft = () => {
        if (closeable) {
            closeModal();
        }
    };

    const closeModalKeyboard = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Escape" && closeable) {
            closeModal();
        }
    };
</script>

<svelte:window on:keydown={closeModalKeyboard}/>

<div class="modal is-clipped" class:is-active={active}>
    <div class="modal-background" on:click={closeModalSoft}/>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
    {#if closeable}
        <button class="is-large modal-close" aria-label="close" on:click={closeModal}/>
    {/if}
</div>
```

It should allow for arbitrary nesting, so you can for example have a modal over a modal over the rest of the website.

I would like to allow for modals be closed by pressing the close button, clicking outside of the modal or using the escape key. I would like this to operate like a stack: the topmost modal gets closed first. (Note: If a modal is not `closeable` as shown in my code, it just means that the modal can only be closed by manipulating `active` externally).

Currently, the close button and clicking outside the modal work with nested modals. However, escape will always close all modals, instead of just the topmost one. But, given the code, I think this is to be expected.

**What would I need to change such that only the topmost (`closeable=true`) modal gets closed?**

I have thought about the following approaches, but I feel like there must be better ways:

- On escape, determine the element at the centre of the screen, and only if its ID is equal to some ID I will give each modal, close it.
- On escape, query the DOM element and see if it has any children/siblings after itself that have both the `modal` and `is-active` classes. If so, ignore the keypress.
- Perhaps use `:focus` or other modifiers on the topmost element and then a similar approach as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the event on the `window` is the wrong approach which leads to this issue.

Modals should not allow focus to leave it, that being the case you should be able to handle the `Escape` press on the Modal itself. The easiest way to get the focus trap "for free" would be to use a native [`dialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element (though it getting [support](https://caniuse.com/dialog) is still relatively recent).

A manual focus trap would have to steer focus on opening/closing and on any `Tab` press. There might be libraries that already implement this. Actually, I would not recommend implementing such generic components anyway and suggest the use of a component library instead. It is easy to get accessibility and things like keyboard interactions *very* wrong.

Guidelines for Modals: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/

Comment: I've done a bit of research and found [this](https://github.com/c0bra/svelma/blob/master/src/components/Modal/Modal.svelte), [this](https://github.com/flekschas/svelte-simple-modal/blob/master/src/Modal.svelte), and [this](https://svelte.jp/examples/modal) as the only libraries that support escape to close modals. I know asking for opinionated things is looked down upon, but are there any libraries that get it right?

Comment: I do not know any that are flawless, though I also have not looked at many. [`carbon-components-svelte`](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte) is pretty good in general, its focus management in the [Modal](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/blob/master/src/Modal/Modal.svelte) is a bit shoddy though, as it does not cover all cases and it focuses the wrong element initially (close button instead of first focusable content element or button).